# How do we optimise the spark job if the base table has 130 billions of records

Tags: performance, apache-spark, optimization, apache-spark-sql

We are joining multiple tables and doing complex transformations and enrichments.
In that the base table will have around 130 billions of records, how can we optimise the spark job when the spark filters all the records keep in memory and do the enrichments with other left outer join tables. Currently spark job is running for more than 7 hours, can you suggest some techniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can try

1. Partition your base tables on which you want to run your query, create partition on specific column like Department, or Date etc which you use during joining. If the under lying table is hive you can also try bucketing.
2. Try optimised joins which suits your requirement such sorted merge join, hash join.
3. File format, use parquet file format as it much faster compared to ORC for analytical queries, and it also stores data in columnar format.
4. If your query has multiple steps and some steps are reused try to use caching, as spark supports memory and disk caching.
5. Tune your spark jobs by specifying the number of partitions, executor, cores, driver memory as per the resources available. Check spark history UI to understand how data is distributed. Try various configurations see what works best for you.
6. Spark might perform poorly if there large skewness in data. if that is the case you might need further optimisation to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above mentioned techniques, you can try below option as well to optimize your job.

1.You can partition your data by inspecting your data fields. Most common columns that are used for partitioning are like date columns, region ID, country code etc.Once data is partitioned your can explain your dataframe like `df.explain()` and see if is using  [PartitioningAwareFileIndex](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/PartitioningAwareFileIndex.html).

2.Try tuning the spark settings and cluster configuration to scale with the input data volume.

- Try changing the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` to 256 MB or 512
  MB , we have see significant performance gain by changing this
  parameter.
- Use appropriate number of executor , cores & executor memory based on
  compute need
- Try analyzing the spark history to identify the stage jobs which are
  consuming significant time. This would be good point to start
  debugging your job.

Answer (score 0):

Salting is the best technique that I have seen to give some benefit in this scenarios. Because whenever we are dealing with billions of records there is a very high chance that the data is skewed.

Eg:

```
val df1 = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM tableA """)

val df2 = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM TABLE B""")

val n = 199

val salt_values = (0 until n).toList
val df2_1 = df2.withColumn("salt_values", array(salt_values.map(lit): _*))
val df2_2 = df2_1.withColumn("_salt_", explode($"salt_values")).drop("salt_values")

val df1_1 = df1.withColumn("_salt_", monotonically_increasing_id() % n)

#  SaltedJoin

val df3 = df2_2.join(df1_1, <your join condition> && df2_2.col("_salt_") === df1_1.col("_salt_"), "inner").drop("_salt_")
```